# byte 24h not found after 2000 bytes. - assembly 8086

Tags: assembly

Im writing a simple calculator (add, sub, mul, div, with options to do powers and modulo) 
in assembly 8086
Im getting an error saying "byte 24h not found after 2000 bytes."
after I print something.
Im pretty sure the error happens when the code reaches line 142 and uses printStr procedure.
Help please?

```
data segment 

menu  db 'Please enter your Choice of action :',10,13      ;action selection screen
      db 'for Add  press +',10,13
      db 'for Sub  press -',10,13
      db 'for Mul  press *',10,13
      db 'for Div  press /',10,13
      db 'for mod  press %',10,13
      db 'for Pow  press ^',10,13
      db 'for Exit press x$'     
enterNum1 db 'Please enter the first number$'
enterNum2 db 'Please enter the second number$' 
error db 'Incorrect option, please try again$'
newline db 13,10,'$'

numStr db ?,?,?
action db ?
num1 db ?
num2 db ?
resultStr db ?,?,?
result db ?    

ends

stack segment
    dw   255  dup(0)
ends

code segment  

printStr:                    
   mov bp,sp
   push dx
   push ax
   mov dx,[bp+2]
   mov ah,9
   int 21h
   pop ax
   pop dx
   ret 2 

inputStr:
    Push bp
    mov bp,sp
    Push ax
    Push si
    mov ah,1
    mov si,[bp+4]
    islo1:
        mov ah,1
        int 21h
        CMP al,13
         JE ishem1
        mov [si],al
        inc si
        JMP islo1
    ishem1:
    mov Byte Ptr[si],'$'
    Pop si
    Pop ax
    Pop bp
ret 2  


strtoint:                   
   Push bp
   mov bp,sp
   Push ax
   Push dx
   Push si
   Push di
   mov ax,0
   mov dl,10
   mov si,[bp+6]
   mov di,[bp+4]
   lo1:
    cmp Byte Ptr[si],'$'
    JE hem1
    mul dl
    mov dh,[si]
    sub dh,30h
    add al,dh
    inc si
    JMP lo1
   hem1:
    mov [di],al
    Pop di
    Pop si
    Pop dx
    Pop ax
    Pop bp
    ret 4   


inttostr:
    Push bp            
    mov bp,sp
    Push ax
    Push dx
    Push si
    Push cx
    mov cx,0
    mov dl,10
    mov si,[bp+6]
    mov ax,[bp+4]
    cmp ax,0
    JZ it01
    lo3:
     cmp al,0
     JZ he1
     mov ah,0
     div dl
     push Ax
     inc Cx
     cmp al,0
     JZ he1 
     JMP lo3
    it01:
     mov cx,1
     JMP it0
    he1:
    l2:
     pop Ax
    it0:
     add ah,30h
     mov [si],ah
     inc si
     loop l2
    mov Byte Ptr[si],'$'
    Pop cx
    Pop si
    Pop dx
    Pop ax
    Pop bp
    ret 4  


plus: 
    push ax

    push offset enterNum1           ; input the first number
    call printStr
    push offset numStr
    call inputStr

    push offset newline
    call printstr 

    push offset numStr              ; convert the string of the first number to an actual number
    push offset num1 
    call strtoint
                                    ; input the second number
    push offset enterNum2
    call printStr
    push offset numStr
    call inputStr 

    push offset newline
    call printstr

    push offset numStr              ; convert the string of the second number to an actual number
    push offset num2 
    call strtoint

    mov al, num1
    add al, num2         
    mov result, al

    push offset resultStr
    push offset result
    call inttostr

    push offset resultStr
    call printstr
    ret



start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

repeat:     
    push offset menu
    call printStr           ; print the menu to the user   


    push offset newline
    call printStr 

    push offset action      ; input the action from the user
    call inputStr
   ; push offset newline
    ;call printStr  

    cmp action,'+'
        JE addition
    cmp action,'-'
        JE subtraction
    cmp action,'*'
        JE multiplication
    cmp action,'/'
        JE devision 

    push offset error        ; if the user didn't enter any of the options, the code will get to here, and the user will be asked to try again
    call printStr     

    push offset newline
    call printStr 
    push offset newline
    call printStr 
    jmp repeat              

    addition:   
        call plus

    subtraction:
      ;  call minus 

    multiplication:
      ;  call star 

    devision:    
      ;  call slash                


mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h  

ends

end start
```

Comment: Byte 24h is the `$` sign that's supposed to terminate your string. So you have an unterminated string somewhere. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: The error occurs when trying to print enterNum1, which is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

printStr does not push and pop BP - which is probably not helping